# how Decimal data type evaluatesto such a long range while it's precision is 29 digits only

Tags: c#, decimal

what is the actual mechanism by which Decimal does calculations upto such a big range(1.7E+308) while it's precision is only 29 digits and it also takes only 8 Bytes.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't - `decimal` only works up to 29 digits *and* the maximum value is 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335.

`double`, however, has fewer significant digits but a *much* bigger range. It does this by becoming much less precise for larger numbers. The exponent part can be much larger in `double` than in `decimal`.

I have articles on [binary](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) and [decimal](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx) floating point arithmetic in .NET which explain the storage format in more detail.

Oh, and `decimal` takes 16 bytes, not 8.

Comment: But then how can we evaluate (7E+307 + 1E+307) using Decimal type ?

Comment: @VIKRAM: You can't. If you use `1E+307m` it gives an error of `Floating-point constant is outside the range of type decimal`. Without the `m`, it's a `double` literal rather than `decimal`.

Comment: @VIKRAM - `Decimal d = 1E307` = error about not being able to convert floating point literal to decimal. `Decimal d = 1E307m` = error about floating point constant being out of range for a decimal. Which Decimal type are you talking about?

Comment: Then what ab't the double mechanism for calculations

Comment: @VIKRAM: Follow the links in my answer to see how the storage works. Basically you get much more precision (in terms of absolute values) for small numbers than big numbers.